# MongoDB aggregate ID's efficiently for bulk searches?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have more than 8 references in a MongoDB document. Those are Object ID's stored in the origin document and in order to get the real data of the foreign I have to make an aggregation query, something like this:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      let: { "department": "$_department" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$department"] }}},
      ],
      as: "department"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: { "path": "$department", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }
  },
```

That is working and instead of ObjectId I got the real department object.

However this takes time and make the finding queries to take lot of time.

I have noticed that I have the same ID's multiple times and it's better to collect all of the unique ID's and just fetch them once from DB and then just reuse the same object.

I don't know any plugin or a service doing so, using MongoDB. I can make one bymyself I just want to know before I work on something like this, if there any kind of a service or package in Github?

Comment: *"I have noticed that I have the same ID's multiple times and it's better to collect all of the unique ID's and just fetch them once from DB and then just reuse the same object."* - So what is it that you think MongoDB is actually doing in that `$lookup` if not exactly that? You appear to be under the impression that it's asking for the same thing multiple times rather than doing a "hash merge" of the matching distinct entries. It's actually the latter. So the "performance problem" here is actually doing "joins" in the first place as opposed to just embedding the data.

Comment: Also "asking for recommendations" is "off-topic".